# Check for k convex polygon

Tags: geometry

Given a list of lengths, how can I check whether it will form a $k$ convex polygon?

For example, given $k=3$, and lengths $1,1,1$, the answer is yes.

Comment: Does $k$  convex polygon imply $k$ sided one? Then, its equilateral triangle

Comment: k sided polygon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only requirement is the triangle inequality, i.e., for all $i$, $a_i<\sum_{j\ne i}a_j$.